# Dropdown menu over Flash player

Tags: html, css, flash, internet-explorer, flowplayer

I have a live event site and list of events in a mouse over menu.

The flash streaming player stays in front of the mouse over menu with all versions of IE.

Wmode parameter solved so many people's problem in the past but it does not work in my case. Here is the rendered flash object for player:

```
<object id="flowplayer" width="100%" height="100%" wmode="transparent" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">

    <!-- load configuration from config.js -->
    <param name="flashvars" value="config=player.aspx?pID=585&amp;config=1">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">

</object>
```

I also tried 'wmode=opaque' and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an educated guess since you didn't add the code, but try this:

```
object{z-index:-1}
.menu{z-index:100}
```

of course .menu should be changed to the class of your menu, but you'll get the idea

Comment: I thing our designers already tried that and then came to me. I ll let them know anyway. Thanks